# How can you tell if a process is a windows process like in task manager

Tags: c#, process

i want to tell if a process is a windows service, eg. in task manager when you try to kill a windows process it stops you.

Comment: As @2017, Raymond Chen described how Task Manager *at that time* [categorized processes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606): "These are terms that Task Manager simply made up ... And completely arbitrary."

Comment: Services are usually started by the System Process.  So you can check the parent process ID to determine the parent.